# Different Outputs for AES Encryption using CryptoJS and AES Encryption in Java

Tags: java, javascript, aes, appcelerator, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt data using AES encryption using cryptoJS. 
I want to transfer the encrypted data To / From the Device / Server. But i'm getting different AES encrypted outputs from device and server(Java).

Following is my code:

Mobile side(USing Titanium Appcelerator):

```
var AES_File = require("aes");
var Pad_File = require("pad-nopadding-min");

function encrypt_data(message) {
    Titanium.API.info("encrypt_data : "+message);

    var key = AES_File.CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('0123456789abcdef');
    var iv = AES_File.CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse('fedcba9876543210');

    //var key = AES_File.CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0123456789abcdef');
    //var iv = AES_File.CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('fedcba9876543210');

    var message = "soldier";
    var padMsg = padString(message);

    var encrypted = AES_File.CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(padMsg, key, { iv: iv, pad:    AES_File.CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding, mode: AES_File.CryptoJS.mode.CBC});

    Titanium.API.log("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
    Titanium.API.log("Encrypted text: " + encrypted.ciphertext);

    return encrypted;
};

function padString(source) {
    var paddingChar = ' ';
    var size = 16;
    var x = source.length % size;
    var padLength = size - x;

    for (var i = 0; i < padLength; i++) source += paddingChar;

    return source;
}

exports.encrypt_data = encrypt_data;
```

My Java code on Server :

```
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.*;

public class AesCipher {

    private static final String algorithm = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";

    private static final byte[] keyValue = new byte[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    private static final byte[] ivValue = new byte[] { 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0' };

    private static final IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(ivValue);
    private static final SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");

    final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    private static String padString(String source) {
        char paddingChar = ' ';
        int size = 16;
        int x = source.length() % size;
        int padLength = size - x;

        for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)
        {
            source += paddingChar;
        }
        return source;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: Encrypt [-d] <cleartext>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (args[0].equals("-d")) {
            if (args.length != 2) {
                System.err.println("Usage: Encrypt [-d] <encrypted_text>");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            String encryptedText = args[1];
            System.out.println("encryptedText  is :"+encryptedText);
            String clearText = AesCipher.decrypt(encryptedText);
            System.out.println(clearText);

        } else {
            String clearText = args[0];
            String encryptedText = AesCipher.encrypt(padString(clearText));
            System.out.println(encryptedText);
        }
    }
 }
```

Please help me, where am i going wrong?

Titanium SDK - 3.5.0

Target Device - Android(above 4.0) and iOS (above 6.0)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please show what the values are that you get after encryption for both.

Comment: Why are you doing your own padding? Since you control both sides of the communication channel, use a standard padding scheme such as PKCS #7.

Comment: Server - j6dSmg2lfjY2RpN91GNgNw==

Comment: Mobile side - "lLTa74eiyE2fweqw7ouBjX8TMhR6xFogkyEpT9efHns="

Comment: Hi Duncan is it because of padding? as at both side same padding method is used. Will try using PKCS-7 padding scheme

Comment: @JackieM I don't know if the padding is at fault, I've not had a chance to look at your code that closely. But it's generally a bad security decision to stray from standard solutions and switching to something standard would reduce your code base, thus narrowing the problem down.

Comment: @Duncan I tried using PKCS5 (as pkcs7 is not there for java). but still got different outputs.
Server side - j6dSmg2lfjY2RpN91GNgN1RZefjLW0sHfumYqh4sq0s=
Mobile side - w7lZrqu/eBF3mw+ravmO1A==

Comment: @Duncan : sorry for the last comment. Making PKCS5 Padding worked. Thanks a lot for helping me out....